# Computing the flow for a nonlinear ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This problem comes from Chicone's book (exercise 1.25).  It asks to find the **flow** (i.e. the solution of the IVP) of the following system of ODEs:

\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= y^{2}-x^{2} \\
\dot{y} &= -2xy
\end{align*}

A hint is given to consider the complex variable $z = x+iy$, but I cannot quite seem to figure out a solution (it is not separable or Hamiltonian).  Numerically, it looks like most solutions lie on a circle containing the origin, and this seems to be hinted at in the question, but I do not see the equation; I tried looking for a quadratic conserved quantity (to reduce the dimensionality of the system) of the form
\begin{align*}
V(x,y) &= ax^{2} + by^{2} + cxy + d x + ey + f,
\end{align*}
but none seems to exist.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: You should have found $\dot z=-z^2$, which is separable.

Comment: Yes, I see now.  I am pretty sure I know how to proceed from there.  Thank you!.